# Is $3\Bbb Z[\frac12]+1-2^\Bbb Z$ a group under addition?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ be the set of dyadic rationals.

Is $3\Bbb Z[\frac12]+1-2^\Bbb Z$ a group under addition?

**My attempt**

I'll take as a premise that $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is an additive group.

I think $x\mapsto3x$ doesn't surject over $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$

I think $x\mapsto x+1$ surjects

I think $x\mapsto x-2^t$ surjects $\Bbb Z[\frac12]\to\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ for all $t\in\Bbb Z$

I think if the three functions composed were a surjection the set would remain unchanged and therefore it would remain a group under addition, is that correct?  But I don't know how to get around $3x$ not being onto say $\{1\}$

Comment: Which map exactly do you want to be a surjection? $3x$ is a term.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $x\mapsto 3x$

Comment: $1$ is not in $3\Bbb Z[\frac12]+1-2^\Bbb Z$. If $1$ were in that set, then for some integers $a,b,c$, you have $\frac{3a}{2^b}=2^c$, which is equivalent to $3a$ being a power of $2$. So that composition of three maps cannot be a surjection onto any set containing $1$ (which is an element of $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$). So if I understand your strategy (trying to claim that this set is equal to $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$) it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @2'59'2 for the counterexample.  That was my strategy. Although calling it a strategy was probably a bit generous on your part!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $3\Bbb Z[\frac12]+1-2^\Bbb Z$:

- contains $0=0+1-2^0$, so maybe it is a group under addition, since it has the additive identity...
- contains $-1=0+1-2^1$
- does not contain $1$. If it did, then $1=3a2^b+1-2^c$ for some integers $a,b,c$. This implies $3a=2^{b+c}$, which is not possible. The left side is an integer, so $b+c$ must be an integer power of $2$, which is not divisible by $3$.

So the set in question contains $-1$, but does not contain an additive inverse for $-1$.

Comment: Very nice. This is actually enough to show that $S:=3\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]+1-2^{\mathbb{Z}} = 3\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}] \cup \left( 3\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}] + 2 \right)$, because if $S$ contains $x$ it also contains all translates of $x$ by elements of $3\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Thanks and @RP_ also, these answers helped me understand the original set better, fwiw my own answer now added may add a some tiny morsel of insight for you too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: you can reduce elements of your set modulo $3$ (since division by $2$ modulo $3$ is the same thing as multiplication by $2$). So now see what you can find out about the reduction modulo $3$ of the elements in your set.

---

I added a second hint, but it was wrong. So let me proceed a bit more carefully: let $x$ be an element of $3\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]+1-2^{\mathbb{Z}}$, and write it as $x=\frac{3y}{2^a}+1-2^b$. We will show that this can't be equal to an integer $1$ modulo $3$. If $a$ is zero, this is clear, since then we must also have $b \geq 0$ to make the expression be equal to an integer, and we end up with $3y+1-2^b$ which is either $0$ or $2$ modulo $3$. If $a > 0$, then we must have $b = -a$ in order to make the fractions cancel (we are assuming $y$ odd of course, so that the fraction $\frac{3y}{2^a}$ can't be simplified), and we have to consider the expression  $\frac{3y}{2^a}+1-\frac{1}{2^a}=\frac{3y-1}{2^a}+1=m$, where $m$ is an integer, or $m-1=\frac{3y-1}{2^a}$, from which we get
$$
2^a(m-1)=3y-1.
$$
Now on the RHS we have something that is $2$ modulo $3$, so $m-1$ can't be divisible by $3$. Hence $m$ can't be $1$ modulo $3$. Here ends the hint.

Comment: I think you underestimate my ineptitude!  If I reduce $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ mod $3$ I guess I'm getting $\Bbb Z[\frac12]/3\Bbb Z$ which is represented by the dyadic rationals in the interval $[0,3)$, which is a group but I don't get the relevance because I don't understand the part you wrote in brackets.

Comment: ok I get this much now.  $x\mapsto2x\pmod 3$ permutes $(0,1,2),(0,2,1)$ so it's an involution, which is the part you wrote in the brackets. Now I can't work out why that means "I can reduce elements of my set mod $3$.

Comment: Ok I think $2^\Bbb Z$ contains $\{1,2,4\}$ which differ by $1,2,3$ and therefore I have a proof that $n\Bbb Z$ is a proper subgroup forall $n\in\Bbb N$. But I'd still like to understand your argument.

Comment: @samerivertwice OK, tried to come up with a better hint.

Comment: Thanks @RP much appreciated, plenty of food for thought here.

Answer (score 0):

No: it contains $2 = 3 + 1 - 2^1$, but it does not contain $2+2=4$, since any rational number of the form $3x + 1 - 2^n$ with $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ must be either $0$ or $2$ modulo $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Z[\frac12]-\frac13\cdot2^\Bbb Z$ is the set of all 2-adic numbers which terminate in alternating $0,1=-\dfrac{2^t}3$.  By definition, this is the set of all numbers $x$ for which $3x$ is a dyadic rational equivalent to $1$ or $2\pmod3$.

$3x+1$ is therefore all the dyadic rationals equivalent to $\{0,2\}\pmod3$ and therefore not a group because $2+2\equiv1\pmod3$ and therefore it is not closed under addition.